# What is the difference between @guest('admin') and @guest?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

From [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#authentication-directives):

```
@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

```
@guest('admin')
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Comment: for the latter one a guard (`admin`) is supplied. More info in docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#introduction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify which `guard` is being used when checking if the user is authenticated.

From the [authentication docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#introduction):

> At its core, Laravel's authentication facilities are made up of "guards" and "providers". Guards define how users are authenticated for each request. For example, **Laravel ships with a `session` guard which maintains state using session storage and cookies**.

So, when using `@guest` by itself, it'll check the authentication status against the default guard.

Alternatively, you may [add custom guards](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards) if needed. The example `config/auth.php` shown in the documentation includes an example of how to add a custom guard:

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

If you need to use the custom guard, then you'd use `@guest('api')` instead (along with updating your config and creating your custom authentication guard as shown in the documentation).

This [blog post](https://jambasangsang.medium.com/laravel-8-multi-authentication-using-guards-f1db629ab1dd) goes into more detail for how you might set things up (if you needed it).